# google authenticator implementation java android

Tags: java, android, google-authenticator

i building an Android application that must have an Google authenticator code(Password) to access to it.
the problem that i generate the serial code of 16 characters but when i try to write the validation code the application told me always that is wrong validation code... the time of the phone and the computer are the same so i donßt know why i does not work ...

here some code that i used :

```
`
//Base32.java
private static final  Base32 INSTANCE = 
    new  Base32("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567"); // RFC 4668/3548

  static  Base32 getInstance() { 
    return INSTANCE;
  }

  // 32 alpha-numeric characters.
  private String ALPHABET;
  private char[] DIGITS;
  private int MASK;
  private int SHIFT;
  private HashMap<Character, Integer> CHAR_MAP;

  static final String SEPARATOR = "-";

  protected  Base32(String alphabet) {
    this.ALPHABET = alphabet;
    DIGITS = ALPHABET.toCharArray();
    MASK = DIGITS.length - 1;
    SHIFT = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(DIGITS.length);
    CHAR_MAP = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < DIGITS.length; i++) {
      CHAR_MAP.put(DIGITS[i], i);
    }
  }

  public static byte[] decode(String encoded) throws DecodingException {
    return getInstance().decodeInternal(encoded);
  }

  protected byte[] decodeInternal(String encoded) throws DecodingException {
    // Remove whitespace and separators
    encoded = encoded.trim().replaceAll(SEPARATOR, "").replaceAll(" ", "");
    // Canonicalize to all upper case
    encoded = encoded.toUpperCase();
    if (encoded.length() == 0) {
      return new byte[0];
    }
    int encodedLength = encoded.length();
    int outLength = encodedLength * SHIFT / 8;
    byte[] result = new byte[outLength];
    int buffer = 0;
    int next = 0;
    int bitsLeft = 0;
    for (char c : encoded.toCharArray()) {
      if (!CHAR_MAP.containsKey(c)) {
        throw new DecodingException("Illegal character: " + c);
      }
      buffer <<= SHIFT;
      buffer |= CHAR_MAP.get(c) & MASK;
      bitsLeft += SHIFT;
      if (bitsLeft >= 8) {
        result[next++] = (byte) (buffer >> (bitsLeft - 8));
        bitsLeft -= 8;
      }
    }
    // We'll ignore leftover bits for now. 
    // 
    // if (next != outLength || bitsLeft >= SHIFT) {
    //  throw new DecodingException("Bits left: " + bitsLeft);
    // }
    return result;
  }

  public static String encode(byte[] data) {
    return getInstance().encodeInternal(data);
  }

  protected String encodeInternal(byte[] data) {
    if (data.length == 0) {
      return "";
    }

    // SHIFT is the number of bits per output character, so the length of the
    // output is the length of the input multiplied by 8/SHIFT, rounded up.
    if (data.length >= (1 << 28)) {
      // The computation below will fail, so don't do it.
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    int outputLength = (data.length * 8 + SHIFT - 1) / SHIFT;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(outputLength);

    int buffer = data[0];
    int next = 1;
    int bitsLeft = 8;
    while (bitsLeft > 0 || next < data.length) {
      if (bitsLeft < SHIFT) {
        if (next < data.length) {
          buffer <<= 8;
          buffer |= (data[next++] & 0xff);
          bitsLeft += 8;
        } else {
          int pad = SHIFT - bitsLeft;
          buffer <<= pad;
          bitsLeft += pad;
        }
      }
      int index = MASK & (buffer >> (bitsLeft - SHIFT));
      bitsLeft -= SHIFT;
      result.append(DIGITS[index]);
    }
    return result.toString();
  }

  @Override
  // enforce that this class is a singleton
  public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    throw new CloneNotSupportedException();
  }

  static class DecodingException extends Exception {
    public DecodingException(String message) {
      super(message);
    }
  }
}`



//CheckCode.java    
...public void onClick(View v) {
        String codeDigited=ed.getText().toString();
        Log.d("codeDigited", codeDigited);
        try {
            if(check_code(codeDigited, 0, 0)==true){
            Intent step = new Intent(this, GoogleAuthenticator.class);
            startActivity(step);
            }else{
             info.setText("passwords doesn't match! oh noes!");
            }
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DecodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static boolean check_code(String secret, long code, long t)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, DecodingException {
        //Base32 codec = new Base32(secret);
        byte[] decodedKey = Base32.decode(secret);

        // Window is used to check codes generated in the near past.
        // You can use this value to tune how far you're willing to go.
        int window = 30;
        for (int i = -window; i <= window; ++i) {
            long hash = verify_code(decodedKey, t + i);

            if (hash == code) {
                System.out.println("right");
                return true;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("OOOOOOOps codec.decode(secret): "+decodedKey.toString());
        // The validation code is invalid.
        return false;
    }

    private static int verify_code(byte[] key, long t)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        byte[] data = new byte[8];
        long value = t;
        for (int i = 8; i-- > 0; value >>>= 8) {
            data[i] = (byte) value;
        }

        SecretKeySpec signKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "HmacSHA1");
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        mac.init(signKey);
        byte[] hash = mac.doFinal(data);

        int offset = hash[20 - 1] & 0xF;

        // We're using a long because Java hasn't got unsigned int.
        long truncatedHash = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            truncatedHash <<= 8;
            // We are dealing with signed bytes:
            // we just keep the first byte.
            truncatedHash |= (hash[offset + i] & 0xFF);
        }

        truncatedHash &= 0x7FFFFFFF;
        truncatedHash %= 1000000;

        return (int) truncatedHash;
    }
```

the codeDigited is the validation code i took from Google authentificator App
but i don know why the code does not work